# Access-Control-Allow-Origin en Codeigniter 4

Tags: codeigniter-4, angular13

Cree una rest api en CI 4 y cuando la pruebo en Postman si me devuelve los datos, pero cuando la consumo desde Angular me marca error.

> Postman:

**http://localhost:8080/usuario**

```
[{"id_usuario":"3","nombres":"Miguel","apaterno":"Infante","amaterno":"Barriga","telefono":"123456789","email":"minfante@abacom.mx","password":"32a346820d1792eb66d8fb834539d048","fecha_creacion":"2020-07-23 10:29:58","foto":"ruta","id_tipo_usuario":"1"},{"id_usuario":"2","nombres":"Luisa","apaterno":"Alvarez","amaterno":"Campos","telefono":"123456789","email":"lalvarez@abacom.mx","password":"32a346820d1792eb66d8fb834539d048","fecha_creacion":"2020-07-23 10:29:58","foto":"ruta","id_tipo_usuario":"1"},{"id_usuario":"1","nombres":"Francisco Javier","apaterno":"Ferruzca","amaterno":"Rojas","telefono":"4423117551","email":"fferruzca@abacom.mx","password":"32a346820d1792eb66d8fb834539d048","fecha_creacion":"2020-07-23 10:29:58","foto":"ruta","id_tipo_usuario":"1"}]
```

> Al cargar vista de Angular

```
Solicitud desde otro origen bloqueada: la política de mismo origen impide leer el recurso remoto en http://localhost:8080/usuario (razón: falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'). Código de estado: 404.

Solicitud de origen cruzado bloqueada: La misma política de origen no permite la lectura de recursos remotos en http://localhost:8080/usuario. (Razón: Solicitud CORS sin éxito). Código de estado: (null).
```

He intentado las siguientes cosas, pero no me queda:

> Colocar CorsFilter en CI4

```
<?php 
namespace App\Filters;

use CodeIgniter\config\Services;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\Response;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface;
use CodeIgniter\Filters\FilterInterface;

class CorsFilter implements FilterInterface
{
    public function after(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, $arguments = null) {}

    public function before(RequestInterface $request, $arguments = null)
    {
        if (array_key_exists('HTTP_ORIGIN', $_SERVER)) {
            $origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'];
        } else if (array_key_exists('HTTP_REFERER', $_SERVER)) {
            $origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
        } else {
            $origin = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        }
        $allowed_domains = array(
            'http://localhost:4200',
            'http://www.testerdemo.ir',
            'https://www.testerdemo.ir',
            '*'
        );

        if (in_array($origin, $allowed_domains)) {
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $origin);
        }

        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-API-KEY, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, observe, enctype, Content-Length, X-Csrf-Token");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");

        $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
        if ($method == "OPTIONS") {
            header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
            die();
        }

    }


}
```

> Colocar encabezados en el controlador:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
```

Ya intenté varias cosas, pero no logro darle solución a mi problema.

Alguien que me pueda apoyar por favor.

Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Puede deshabilitar la verificación de seguridad de Edge o Chrome

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --user-data-dir="C://Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security`
Con esto podrás desarrollar mientras tu app no este en producción